# Insert <a> Into a div generated by a plugin with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working with a plugin that provides **IDX data** for listings on a WordPress website. The plugin uses jQuery to query a database for information that it displays on the page. The plugin is not very customizable past simple styling and I would like to insert a link to `save to favorites`

The link for saving to favorites can be found by viewing this page:

http://angelandpatty.com/homes-for-sale-details/8635-La-Entrada-Avenue-Whittier-CA-90605/PW14217291/306/

All the property details pages have the "save to favorites" button at the top of the page. This is what I found with the inspector:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ihfsaveListing" class="btn btn-primary btn-detail-leadcapture save-listing-btn"> <span class="hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fs-12"></i> Save To Favorites </span> <span class="visible-xs fs-12"> Save To<br>Favorites </span> </a>
```

I am assuming the data-target is what is causing the button to take action.

What I would like to do is find a way to insert this same button, perhaps with a different icon like a thumbs up or a star, into the property stubs.

The property stubs are viewable on pages like this:

http://angelandpatty.com/homes-for-sale-in-friendly-hills/

I would like to find a way to insert this possibly after `#ihf-main-container .col-xs-9`

If there is any way to do this with `Javascript` or with `jQuery` I sure would like to know.

Thank you for all of your assistance. I tried searching for some situation like this but was unlucky

Comment: I did a search and tried to paste this into the html before the shortcode to put the listings but it did not seem to work.                                                                      $( "<a href="/test"><i class="fa-star"></i></a>" ).insertAfter( ".ihf-grid-result-basic-info-container" );

Comment: the answer here is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the following answer?

```
 var button = $('<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ihfsaveListing" class="btn btn-primary btn-detail-leadcapture save-listing-btn"> <span class="hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fs-12"></i> Save To Favorites </span> <span class="visible-xs fs-12"> Save To<br>Favorites </span> </a>');

 $('#ihf-main-container .col-xs-9:first').after(button);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/after/

> **.after(content [, content ] )**
>   Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

You may need to initialize the `button` as required.

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to achieve. Where do you want the button to appear? Take some screenshot and attached to your question. I'll check this thread again later.

Comment: Hey Nik, thanks so much for your response. I want to display a little star. I have font awesome icons so i tried to do this on my page in wordpress. 'code'<script>$( "<a href="/test"><i class="fa-star"></i></a>" ).insertAfter( ".ihf-grid-result-basic-info-container" );</script>'code'  I am not sure how to implement what you sent me. I want the new element to display after the .ihf-grid-result-basic-info-container

Comment: I want to put a star or thumbs up that works like the "save to favorites" on the first page. It will go after the SQ FT in the photo

Comment: i just cant get it to work. I dont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: i tried this: <script type="text/javascript">$( init );function init() {$('.ihf-grid-result-basic-info-container').append( "<a href="/abput"><i class="fa-star"></i></a>" );}</script>     didnt work

Comment: tried this as well:  <script>$( “.ihf-grid-result-basic-info-container” ).after( ” <i class=”glyphicon glyphicon-heart fs-12″></i>” );</script>
[optima_express_search_results cityId=”954″ propertyType=”SFR,CND” sortBy=”pd” displayType=”grid” resultsPerPage=”18″ header=”true” includeMap=”false”]